# How can I change this code to accept decimal values inside array?

Tags: c#, arrays, console, decimal

My problem is how to make my array accept decimal values.
The code is good for integers but i need it adjusted for decimal values.I tried to use `Convert.ToDecimal(Console.ReadLine())`, but it wont work. Here is error message:

> Error 1 Cannot implicitly convert type '`decimal`' to '`int`'. An explicit conversion exists (are you missing a cast?)

The problem is, how do I use a decimal in for loop?

I really need it to be like this, because I dont need to put prevalued number for quantity of values for my array or something like that. I need to enter number for size of array, then to enter a number that are a decimal in nature.

Here is the code:

```
public int Unos_brojeva() 
{
    Console.WriteLine("Unesi broj clanova niza:");
    int [] broj = new int[Convert.ToInt32 (Console.ReadLine())];
    Console.WriteLine("Unesi brojeve:");
    for (int i = 0; i < broj.Length; i++)
    { 
        broj[i] = (Convert.ToInt32 (Console.ReadLine()));
    }

    Console.WriteLine("Unos je zavrsen");
    Console.ReadLine();
    return 0;
}

static void Main()
{
    BrojniNiz brojka;
    brojka = new BrojniNiz();
    brojka.Unos_brojeva();
}
```

Comment: "but it wont work" --- we need to guess the exception message now?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Have you tried changing it to a decimal array (`decimal[]`)?

```
decimal[] broj = new decimal[Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine())];
for (int i = 0; i < broj.Length; i++)
{
    broj[i] = Convert.ToDecimal(Console.ReadLine());
}
```

Comment: Thanks brother.It works.I tried different aprouch(and failed).Just to let you what i tri before : decimal[] broj = new decimal[Convert.ToDecimal(Console.ReadLine())]; Sorry about my poor english.This my third day with c# and VS express 2012.Thanks for help.

Comment: @VeljkoStefanovic That's close, but the size of an array *must* be an `int` (or implicitly convertable to an `int`). So you read the size as an `int`, then you can read each element as a `double`. Happy coding :)

Answer (score 1):

ok so if you want the input value within the array to be a decimal, then you should initialize the array as a decimal array.

```
int[] intArray = new int[<size of the array>];
decimal[] decimalArray = new decimal[<size of this array>];
```

hope that helps.